# How to get a function to convert state names to the corresponding abbreviations

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I apologize if this question has been answered but I have searched high and low and haven't been able to figure this out. I have a MySQL database that stores customer addresses and I would like to be able to pull the addresses from the table and print them for mailing from the webpage. The problem is that the state names are not in their abbreviated form in the table so I have been trying to convert them. When I pull the data I store it to an array. The array that holds the states is called $state and I use a counter ($data) to pull each set of values from each array. Here is the code I have for the function:

```
function convertState($name){
   switch($name){
    case "Alabama":
        return "AL";
        break;
    case "Alaska":
        return "AK";
        break;
    case "Arizona":
        return "AZ";
        break;
    [ ... list all other states ... ]
    case "Wyoming":
        return "WY";
        break;
    case "Other" || "other":
        return $province;
        break;
    default:
        return; 
}
```

It looks to me like it should work but when I try to pass it like this: `convertState($state[$data]);`
Nothing happens all the state names are still spelled out. I would like it to convert each state to it's abbreviation as it is printed.

Comment: Could it be a lower/upper case issue?
try something like this and see what happens?
    switch( strtolower ($name ) ) { case "wyoming":   return "WY";   break; }

Comment: you are already calling it like this: `$state[$data] = convertState($state[$data]);` right? because the function will return the converted value, will not change it in the passed argument

Comment: No I wasn't calling it like that. Oops. Thank you it works perfectly! The case "Other" || "other": return $province; break; is the only aspect that doesn't work now but I think I can figure that part out. Thanks again!

Comment: @Wayfrae `case "Other": case "other": ... break;` is the way to do that

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a case statement have you thought of an associative array where the state's name is the key and the abbreviation the value?

for example:

```
$states = array(
  "Alabama" => "AL", 
  "Alaska"=> "AK" ...
);
```

Then when you need the abbreviation you get it by passing the state name as the key.

$states['Alabama'] would return 'AL'

Comment: Is this a better way to do it?

Comment: Short answer, yes. It will also be faster. In a case statement if you are looking for Wyoming, the name has to get compared to all the cases before it. I would recommend tho that you make all the keys lower case as others said and use strlower on the name before using it as a key.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using some sort of loop as you state that `$data` is the index for the state right? Which leads me to believe that your `$state` array looks like this (*correct me if I'm wrong*):

```
$state = ["Alabama", "Alaska", ......etc];
```

And you'd be using a loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($states); $i++) {
    convertState($states[$i]);
}
```

Or a `foreach()` loop potentially.

The issue is that you're returning the value and not assigning it. What you could do, as stated in the comments by [`@guido`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389099/guido), this:

```
$state[$data] = convertState($state[$data]);
```

To assign the correct value. Or you could use [PHP's by-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and do something like this:

```
function convertState(&$name){
   switch($name){
    case "Alabama":
        $name = "AL";
        break;
    case "Alaska":
        $name = "AK";
        break;
    ...........
    ...... etc
    default:
        return;
    }
    return $name;
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/288349)

Comment: Yes I am using a while loop because I want to be able to choose the customer info from a specific date window.